# Convert Keras model to TensorFlow protobuf

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, tensorflow, keras

We're currently training various neural networks using Keras, which is ideal because it has a nice interface and is relatively easy to use, but we'd like to be able to apply them in our production environment.

Unfortunately the production environment is C++, so our plan is to:

- Use the TensorFlow backend to save the model to a protobuf
- Link our production code to TensorFlow, and then load in the protobuf

Unfortunately I don't know how to access the TensorFlow saving utilities from Keras, which normally saves to HDF5 and JSON. How do I save to protobuf?

Comment: Not familiar with Keras, but if it's using the default graph, you can get the protobuf as  `tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()`

Answer (score 7):

In case you don't need to utilize a GPU in the environment you are deploying to, you could also use my library, called frugally-deep. It is available on GitHub and published under the MIT License: https://github.com/Dobiasd/frugally-deep

frugally-deep allows running forward passes on already-trained Keras models directly in C++ without the need to link against TensorFlow or any other backend.

Comment: Any plans to support RNNs? Interesting overlap with [lwtnn](https://github.com/lwtnn/lwtnn) which handles RNNs (but not convolutions).

Comment: @Shep I would like to support them in the future, but I don't have a schedule planned for this yet.

Answer (score 4):

You can access TensorFlow backend by:

```
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as K
```

Then you can call any TensorFlow utility or function like:

```
K.tf.ConfigProto
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be answered in ["Keras as a simplified interface to TensorFlow: tutorial"](http://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html), posted on *The Keras Blog* by Francois Chollet.

In particular, [section II, "Using Keras models with TensorFlow"](http://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html#using-keras-models-with-tensorflow).

Answer (score 2):

Save your keras model as an HDF5 file.

You can then do the conversion with the following code:

```
from keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_io

weight_file_path = 'path to your keras model'
net_model = load_model(weight_file_path)
sess = K.get_session()

constant_graph = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, sess.graph.as_graph_def(), 'name of the output tensor')
graph_io.write_graph(constant_graph, 'output_folder_path', 'output.pb', as_text=False)
print('saved the constant graph (ready for inference) at: ', osp.join('output_folder_path', 'output.pb'))
```

Here is my sample code which handles multiple input and multiple output cases:
https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you change the **learning phase of keras backend** to store proper values of the layers (like dropout or batch normalization). Here is a [discussion](https://ai-pool.com/d/problem_after_converting_keras_model_into_tensorflow_pb) about it.