# Use Keras to set up Neural Network, then train it using the TF C++ API

Tags: c++, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras with TF backend. I want to set up a neural network with keras using python, then save it, convert it to tensorflow and train it using TF's C++ API.

What I have found so far was already pretty helpful:

1) [Run your Keras models in C++ Tensorflow](http://www.bitbionic.com/2017/08/18/run-your-keras-models-in-c-tensorflow/)

2) [Convert Keras model to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720498/convert-keras-model-to-c)

Unfortunately both approaches use Keras to train the NN and convert it to TF afterwards. Basically, I just want to set up the architecture using Keras and then train the network using TF's C++ API. Is there a way to do so?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why the downvote? I have the exact same problem. The reason to do so is because using Keras for the training is too slow, with the bottlenect being converting `Numpy` array to `Tensor` after doing Preprocessing in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the second link you [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720498/convert-keras-model-to-c), is just enough what you need. You may need to search on "Save and Load Your Keras Deep Learning Models" and then open it with the TF's C++ API.