# Convert Keras model to C

Tags: c, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am using Keras (with Tensorflow) to train my RNN model. Does anyone has an idea how can I use it in my C application? Does anyone tried something similar?

I found a similar question here how to use Tensorflow Keras model in C++ here [Convert Keras model to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720498/convert-keras-model-to-c) but i want to convert it to a C environment.

Comment: Hi, did you work this out? I have similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never tried, but this can be a way to do it. Firstly, convert the Keras model to Tensorflow, with tools like [this](https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow) one or following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@pipidog/how-to-convert-your-keras-models-to-tensorflow-e471400b886a). After this step, you can use your model with the [tf C API](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c).

Comment: I think you can skip the convertation from keras to tensorflow, because you can create a .pb file from keras directly.